# How to properly add `mock` package to Android Studio project?

Tags: android-studio

I want Android Studio to recognize my `mock` folder by putting `mock` at the end of the package name while in the `Android` pane.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

I've tried different combinations of:

- right-clicking -> new package
- right-clicking -> new Java Folder
- declaring `sourceSets` in Gradle like so:

  sourceSets {
      mock {
          java.srcDir 'src/mock'
      }
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add Mock as a **flavor**

```
productFlavors {
    mock {
        applicationIdSuffix = ".mock"
        dimension "default"
    }
    prod {
        dimension "default"
    }
}

// Remove mockRelease as it's not needed.
android.variantFilter { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name == 'release'
            && variant.flavors[0].name == 'mock') {
        variant.ignore = true
    }
}
```